# How do you append data to json with python?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to append some data to my json file in python for my discord bot. However, I can only get data to replace other strings of data. here is the code I have:

```
@client.command()
async def banTest(ctx, member: discord.Member, days=0, hours=0, minutes=0, *, reason="None"):
    user = ctx.author
    seconds = 0
    if days == 0 and hours == 0 and minutes == 0:
        moderatorActions = {
            "bans":
                [
                    {
                        "username": f"{member}",
                        "bannedBy": f"{user}",
                        "banDate": f"{datetime.date.today()} at {datetime.datetime.now().time()}",
                        "reason": f"{reason}",
                        "banTimeRemaining": "INDEFINITE"
                    }
                ]
        }
    else:
        hours = hours + (days * 24)
        minutes = minutes + (hours * 60)
        seconds = seconds + (minutes * 60)
        moderatorActions = {
            "bans":
                [
                    {
                        "username": f"{member}",
                        "bannedBy": f"{user}",
                        "banDate": f"{datetime.date.today()} at {datetime.datetime.now().time()}",
                        "reason": f"{reason}",
                        "banTimeRemaining":
                            [
                              {"seconds": [f"{seconds}"]}
                            ]
                    }
                ]
        }
    with open('moderatorActionLogs.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    data.update(moderatorActions)
    with open('moderatorActionLogs.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

How to use:
/banTest @user#1234 7 5 30 rude behavior toward staff

I'm using this json file to store how much time a user has left on their ban. How would  I go about adding users to this list, instead of replacing them?

(also, any help with how to subtract one from the 'seconds' variable every second so the temporary ban function actually works would be great)

Thanks! (:

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: It's just an example, try same as based on your data tree

```
import json

with open('moderatorActionLogs.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data['id'] = 134 # <--- add `id` value.
    f.seek(0)        # <--- should reset file position to the beginning.
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    f.truncate()     # remove remaining part
```

does it make sense to you?

Comment: I'm afraid not, haha! Would I be able to just copy/paste into my code? If so, where would I put it, and what should I replace it with?

Comment: Ive tried to implement your suggestion but without success. If you could show me how and where to put this in, that would be great! thanks